# Controller not retaining scope when navigating away

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I need assistance here.  Two issues.

1. My service can return up to three different responses depending on which button the user clicks.  And if the user views option A then selects option B or C, the same service gets called awaiting a response.  However, if the user selects option A...then goes to option B and back again to option A, its forcing a new HTTP$ response...but I am trying to return a cached view of the option/response A.  How can I store each response, in the service or controller, so that when the user reselects the option, it pulls from the stored/cached response.  The only time is should pull a new response is if that data points have changed.
2. If the user leaves the controller and returns, the $scope is wiped out and it must call the services again (even if the datapoints haven't changed).  I want the service to retain the response(s) just like in #1 above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using Caching mechanism instead of focusing on ways to retain SCOPE or ROOTSCOPE variable values.

You may refer to 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory
which will give you enough details.

I can suggest these steps :

1.Setup the cache very first time user hits your service (for each options A, B, C) and store each responses in cache with KEY, VALUE pair mapping.
PSEUDO CODE:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
cache.put("ServiceCallForOption-A", "value");
cache.put("ServiceCallForOption-B", "another value for B");
cache.put("ServiceCallForOption-C", "another value for C");
```

2. Every time the next request is made for these again, fetch it from cache instead of fetching it from your controller.
   PSEUDO CODE: `cache.get(key);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah...cool.  This gives me a new direction to think about.  Thanks.

Comment: trying out my first $cacheFactory("myCache") - once I set a value in cache: `myCache.put("ServiceA",$scope.optionA)`, whats the best way to reset `ServiceA`?  do I do another `myCache.put("ServiceA,$scope.optionA)`, or can you even do a `myCache("ServiceA") = $scope.optionA`.  I need to test if "ServiceA" is set, if not, set it...if so, blow it away and reset it.

Comment: You can check for value for your corresponding key (here key is ServiceA by doing myCache.get(ServiceA)). If this has been set earlier, this key will be present in cache and value returned will be not null.

Comment: Thanks again.  You got me on the right track using $cacheFactory - which oddly enough, I wasn't even aware existed as a programmable option.  I figured it out and is 10x cleaner than any of my previous attempts to get this working.

Comment: I am happy to share something which helped you in your project.